# The script works, but only for a limited amount of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My original spreadsheet contains a website's pricing. I then run a script to to change the format, and create a few new columns that my website needs. The input of these are are based on the original spreadsheet.

For example; the original has "title" and the resulting spreadsheet has "title" and "SEO title". The script just copies the content for "title" in both columns and trims SEO if its too long.

I would like to edit the script to give me a new column (AS2) with an alternative price based on a simple calculation: the column called "price" (F2) * 1.18.

The script works great for a limited amount of rows. I first add a column called "Website RRP". Then within that column all the vales should have the result of multiplying the column called "price" by 1.18.

But once I have more than 2/3,000 rows, the process times out.

I'm unsure how I could make my code any simpler to help decreasing the processing time.

```
ss.getRange("AS2").setFormula("=F2*1.18");
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 45, lr-1);
ss.getRange("AS2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

If F2 is 1.00, I expect the output of AS2 to be 1.18, and the same for F8000 and AS8000. But the script times out.

I start my code with the following to define the columns

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shSKU=ss.getActiveSheet();
var skuData=shSKU.getDataRange().getValues();

var finalData=[];
var i,j;
finalData[0]=[];
for(i=0;i<skuData[0].length;i++)
finalData[0].push(skuData[0][i]);   

finalData[0].push("Website RRP");
```

I then get my data into an array

```
for(j=0;j<skuData[i].length;j++)
{
  finalData[count].push(skuData[i][j]);
}

var arr=strip_html_tags(skuData[i][23]);
finalData[count].push(skuData[i][2]);
finalData[count].push(arr[0]);
finalData[count].push(arr[1]);
finalData[count].push("");
finalData[count].push("");
count++;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear either “`AS2`” is the name of your column or you refer to the cell `AS2` (column `AS`, row `2`). In any case `ss.getRange("AS2")`.`setFormula("=F2*1.18")`; cannot work for the whole script. You need to create a loop that is iterating through all cells of column `AS` and applies the formula to them.  Please check the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  for(var i = 2; i < lr; i++) {
   var destination ="AS"+i;
   var formula = "F" + i + "*1.18";
   ss.getRange(destination).setFormula(formula);
  }
}
As for:
var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 45, lr - 1);
ss.getRange("AS2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

If you want to copy the values of `AS` rather than the formula (which would mean `AR * 1.18`) you have to replace

```
ss.getRange("AS2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
```

by

```
fillDownRange.setValues(ss.getRange("AS2:AS").getValues())
```

Comment: Apologies, I meant AS, which I define as "Website RRP". I've edited the post to give you more detail. Thank you!

Comment: Does my code work for you? How is the implementation of your array related to the implementation of the formula with which you had problems?

Comment: Yes but it moves all the other new columns around. So instead of the "Website RRP" column being last, it adds several empty columns, followed by "Website RRP"  and then the other several new columns.

Comment: If you are talking about fillDownRange.setValues(ss.getRange("AS2:AS").getValues()); - I just saw there was a typo - please replace "J2:J" through "AS2:AS"